# How Do I add data to a table in MySQL from another table And FORM inputs

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I'm currently working on a task for a web developer job. The task is creating a simple product list and add product pages.

The Tricky part is that at the add product page, there are always-visible inputs such as:

- product name
- product sku
- product price
- product type (digital, book, furniture)

and another one or more input fields when I specify the product type.

Here is an image of what the design should look like:
[task mochup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf0mb.png)

At the data base I've created 4 tables as follows:

[database design scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iofls.png)

---

#### Here is a sample from the data coming form the add-product form:

```php
$_POST['name'];
$_POST['sku'];
$_POST['price'];
$_POST['typeId'];
// incase the typeId == 1
$_POST['size'];
// incase the typeId == 2
$_POST['weight'];
// incase the typeId == 3
$_POST['height'];
$_POST['width'];
$_POST['length'];
```

For the name,sku and the price; they'd be added to the products table.

the typeId is already stored at the product_category table like this:

| id | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dvd |
| 2 | book |
| 3 | furniture |

and here is the table of variant_name:

| id | name | product_category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | size | 1 |
| 2 | weight | 2 |
| 3 | height | 3 |
| 4 | width | 3 |
| 5 | length | 3 |

And here is the type_variants table:

| id | var_name_id | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 3 | ## |
| 4 | 4 | ## |
| 5 | 5 | ## |

My Idea for inserting the values to the type_variants table is getting the `$_POST['typeId']` then join that value to the variant_name, so that I can add the values respectively to the table.

Here is the sql command that I usually run:

```sql
INSERT INTO `type_variants`(`var_name_id`, `values`)
-- select the id form variant names table
SELECT name.id
FROM variant_name AS name JOIN product_category AS cat ON name.product_category_id = cat.id
WHERE cat.id = 3
-- add both the id and the incoming value
VALUES (`name.id`,'30'), (`name.id`,'50'), (name.id,'15')
LIMIT 0,3;
```

After some few searches I've realized that we can't use SELECT and VALUES while inserting data into the table.

But my approach is adding data to this table based on the id from the names table + the data coming from the form.

So I'm unable to find a solution using the subquery.

Any HELP!!!

Comment: You can include static data in the `SELECT` but they would be fixed values so they'd be the same for each row inserted. Is there a reason you're not simply querying first, then doing the insert?

Comment: Which mysql version are you using ?

Comment: Please post example data and the desired end-results.

Comment: @nbk, I'm using version 5.6 that's the required version for the test.

Comment: @WillB.
An example is probably best to check the task mockup, the image may explain better than my description. But for example. If a user selects furniture; there would be 3 values to send, height - width - length, unlike the other 2 types; that only send 1 value. That's why it's tricky. Because I want to send all values and each corresponding values goes to their respected id from the scheme. It's a little bit confusing I know. But I'm seeking help as much as I can.

Comment: I took a look at the images but some sample data of what the form would be sending via `$_POST` and the desired end-results that go into the database, go a lot further to ensure your expectations are being met in the answers. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details. Please edit your question to update it with as much insight as you can provide.

Comment: @WillB. 
I've updated the post, can you check it out please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, as you see cat as table is not necessary

```
INSERT INTO `type_variants`(`var_name_id`, `values`)
-- select the id form variant names table
SELECT name.id, inval.val
FROM variant_name AS name CROSS JOIN (SELECT 30 as val UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION SELECT 15) inval WHERE name.product_category_id = 3
LIMIT 0,3;
```

> ```
> Table 'fiddle.type_variants' doesn't exist
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9RwUYbvs)

So after thinking about your problem , i thin you have something like the below and then you would rewrite it like this

```
CREATE tABLe type_variants(`var_name_id` bigint, `values` int)
```

```
CREATE TABLE variant_name(id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, product_category_id BIGint)
```

```
INSERT INTO variant_name (product_category_id) VALUEs (3),(3),(3),(4),(4),(4),(5),(5),(5)
```

> ```
> Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
INSERT INTO `type_variants`(`var_name_id`, `values`)
-- select the id form variant names table
SELECT name.id, inval.val
FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY product_category_id ORDER BY id) rn 
  FROM variant_name   WHERE product_category_id = 3)
  AS name INNER JOIN  (SELECT 30 as val, 1 as rn UNION ALL SELECT 50,2 UNION SELECT 15,3) inval 
ON name.rn = inval.rn
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM type_variants
```

| var_name_id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 15 |

```
INSERT INTO `type_variants`(`var_name_id`, `values`)
-- select the id form variant names table
SELECT name.id, inval.val
FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY product_category_id ORDER BY id) rn 
  FROM variant_name   WHERE product_category_id IN (4,5))  AS name INNER JOIN  (SELECT 30 as val, 1 as rn UNION ALL SELECT 50,2 UNION SELECT 15,3) inval 
ON name.rn = inval.rn
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM type_variants
```

| var_name_id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 30 |
| 5 | 50 |
| 6 | 15 |
| 7 | 30 |
| 8 | 50 |
| 9 | 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YASqGq_K)

Comment: This command only adds the value 30, three times.

Comment: A cross join would not do that , pkease change the fiddle with actual data and post the link here

Comment: Also ypu should remove the limit clause @AhmadKhaled that is ptobably the cause ehy only have 3 rows

Comment: When I remove the limit, it ends up adding each value 3 times, so the total records would be 9 at the end. and this is not what I'm seeking.

Comment: Like i said change my fiddle and show your problem with a [mre]

Comment: i can not guess if your have 3 ids for every product_catgory or d id is a auti_incrment). the strucrure defines how the qzery must llook like

Comment: i have updated the answer to show how you can adept the answer, to your needs, if you have the same staructure, if you have something different you need to adept it further